# Reading from two files and taking cross product

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am reading two files and I want for each line in file one sum up all the lines in file two. So far I have written the code below but it only does it for the first line in the files. Below is my code and sample files. Note I am getting `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    public class knn {
    public static void main (String[]args)throws IOException{
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("knn.txt"));
      Scanner in2 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("knn2.txt"));
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
           String linetoprocess = in.nextLine();
           StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linetoprocess, " :");
             while(in2.hasNextLine()){
                String linetoprocess2 = in2.nextLine();
                StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(linetoprocess2, " :");
                System.out.print("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
                System.out.print("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
                System.out.print("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
                System.out.print("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
                System.out.print("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
                System.out.print("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
                System.out.print("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
                System.out.print("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
               System.out.println("("+st.nextToken()+","+st2.nextToken()+")");

            }
        }
    }
```

knn.txt

> 1 1:5.1 2:3.5 3:1.4 4:0.2
>   1 1:4.9 2:3.0 3:1.4 4:0.2
>   1 1:4.7 2:3.2 3:1.3 4:0.2

knn2.txt

> 1 1:5.4 2:3.7 3:1.5 4:0.2
>   1 1:4.8 2:3.4 3:1.6 4:0.2
>   1 1:4.8 2:3.0 3:1.4 4:0.1
>   1 1:4.3 2:3.0 3:1.1 4:0.1

Comment: Provide a sample output so we can see what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: (1,1), (1,1), (5.1,5.4), (2,2), (3.5,3.7), (3,3), (1.4,1.5), (4,4), (0.2,0.2)-----
(1,1), (1,1), (5.1,4.8), (2,2), (3.5,3.4), (3,3), (1.4,1.6), (4,4), (0.2,0.2)

Comment: I got it I should have called called the st.nextToken() before the inner while loop. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it I should have called called the st.nextToken() before the inner while loop and store them in a variable which I can use later. Thanks for your suggestions. The complete code is below.

```
import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 public class knn {
 public static void main (String[]args)throws IOException{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("knn.txt"));

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        String linetoprocess = in.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linetoprocess, " :");
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("knn2.txt"));
        String a = st.nextToken();
        String b = st.nextToken();
        String c = st.nextToken();
        String d = st.nextToken();
        String e = st.nextToken();
        String f = st.nextToken();
        String g = st.nextToken();
        String h = st.nextToken();
        String i = st.nextToken();

        while(in2.hasNextLine()){
        String linetoprocess2 = in2.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(linetoprocess2, " :");
        System.out.print("("+a+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
        System.out.print("("+b+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
        System.out.print("("+c+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
        System.out.print("("+d+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
        System.out.print("("+e+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
        System.out.print("("+f+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
        System.out.print("("+g+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
        System.out.print("("+h+","+st2.nextToken()+"), ");
        System.out.println("("+i+","+st2.nextToken()+")");

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer has gone out of fashion, in favor of String.split(...)

But as far as fixing your code, I would suggest that you should add another while around StringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens

Comment: I got it I should have called called the st.nextToken() before the inner while loop. Thanks for your suggestions.